# Difference between var and env in Github action

Tags: bash, shell, github, github-actions

I am new to Github action and seeing the vars and env as given here - https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables

I am converting a jenkins pipeline (groovy) to Github action. The groovy script currently defines a lot of variables that will be used throughout the pipeline (some environment specific and some inputs and some used in the stages).

```
def RESOURCE_URL             = ''
def CHECK_DIR                = ''
```

Is the understanding correct that in Github action the variables store info that are related to configuration and env has variables that are passed around (with context) in the steps?

If I need to save values between steps is the correct approach to set it in env?

Comment: See [Migrating from Jenkins to GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/manual-migrations/migrating-from-jenkins-to-github-actions).

Comment: Aslo, see [Migrating from Jenkins with GitHub Actions Importer](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/automated-migrations/migrating-from-jenkins-with-github-actions-importer).

Comment: Just because you saw Jenkins did you put it to migrating jenkins actions ? Don't you think a google search will get that . I am trying to understand all my variables is it best practice (or understanding) to put as env (as shown in migrate), if so then what is the use of var?

Comment: Well, no. I started to write an answer and then thought it's better to share that link as it has that one-to-one mapping which would be more helpful. BTW, your understanding is correct. Another thing that might be helpful would be the [output paramters](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter) to share values between steps and jobs.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your taking time. One question I can pass as env or output between steps (using the id). Can outputs take JSON values (from a python script?) - it said multi-line hence requesting the clarification.

Comment: Sure, no problem. You can pass both an env var and an output parameter between steps. For passing the output parameter, you'll need the `id`, not with an env var. See [Setting an environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) and [Setting an output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter) for more details and examples. Yes, sure, you can pass JSON. You can easily find many threads for such use cases on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the understanding correct that in Github action the variables store info that are related to configuration and env has variables that are passed around (with context) in the steps?

Yes, correct.

See [`env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#env-context) and [`vars`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#vars-context) contexts for more details.

> If I need to save values between steps is the correct approach to set it in env?

You may use an env var or an output parameter.

See [Setting an environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) and [Setting an output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter) for more details and examples.

Also, see [Defining outputs for jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs).

There may be other approaches too such as generating an intermediate file to share data between steps of a job or uploading/downloading artifacts to share between jobs. See [Storing workflow data as artifacts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts).

---

Here are some related helpful threads:

- [Migrating from Jenkins to GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/manual-migrations/migrating-from-jenkins-to-github-actions)
- [Migrating from Jenkins with GitHub Actions Importer](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/automated-migrations/migrating-from-jenkins-with-github-actions-importer)